# How can I store a three element tuple in AWS SSM parameter with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating private subnets with Terraform:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count = length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)

  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, count.index + 10)
  availability_zone       = element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.client_code}-${var.environment}-private-${element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

Later I'm trying to create SSM parameter with:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "private_subnets_ids" {
  name  = "/${var.client_code}-${var.environment}/backend/SUBNET_IDS"
  type  = "StringList"
  value = aws_subnet.private.*.id
}
```

As subnets resource is making three subnets, it raises the following error:

```
   4:   value = aws_subnet.private.*.id
    |----------------
    | aws_subnet.private is tuple with 3 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.
```

How should I pass this three element tuple to the `StringList` type parameter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`value` parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter#value) for the [`aws_ssm_parameter` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter) needs to be a string type regardless of the `type` specified. In fact, AWS always expects parameters to be of a string type as seen in [the API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_Parameter.html) and mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044174/aws-systems-manager-parameter-store-using-stringlist-as-key-value-pairs-in-java) and the `StringList` type is essentially metadata for the client to expect it to be a string that contains other strings concatenated together by a comma character.

To convert your tuple type from `aws_subnet.private.*.id` into a list you can join it with the [`join` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html) like this:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "private_subnets_ids" {
  name  = "/${var.client_code}-${var.environment}/backend/SUBNET_IDS"
  type  = "StringList"
  value = join(",", aws_subnet.private.*.id)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, as always :) Small correction to anwser: `value = join(",", aws_subnet.private.*.id)` - coma was missing

Answer (score 0):

Here is full example:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "SubnetIDs" {
  name        = "SubnetIDs"
  description = "SubnetIDs"
  type        = "StringList"
  value       = join(", ", aws_subnet.private-subnet.*.id)
}
```