# How to pass json inside the terraform variable?

Tags: terraform, aws-ssm

I am trying to create an AWS parameter store via terraform that can also pass default values with the JSON format. Here is a sample of the code.

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "secret" {
  name        = "/something/env"
  description = "This is a something values"
  type        = "SecureString"
  value       = "test"
  
  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }
}
```

Instead of passing out a single value as a "test" from value, how can I pass the json one inside value one.

So that AWS parameter store value will be like

```
{
   "key": "value"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I store a three element tuple in AWS SSM parameter with Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916301/how-can-i-store-a-three-element-tuple-in-aws-ssm-parameter-with-terraform)

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε no it doesn't answer my question

Comment: It is currently unclear what you are asking, Could you please show an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard I have forgotten to add the intro about the issue. I have updated. If there are anything to need please let me know

Comment: Your example resource of what you are trying to achieve has no JSON inside it, and is also valid. Is it accurate? What is the error?

Comment: @MattSchuchard in the above sample code, it's valid, if I let to pass using there, it won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html), which could be used as such:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "secret" {
  name        = "/something/env"
  description = "This is a something values"
  type        = "SecureString"
  value = jsonencode({
    "key" : "value"
  })

  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }
}
```

Comment: A common way to set up the key-value pair(s) is with generic secrets registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/… 

For example: 
`value = jsonencode({ 
  "secret" : "${data.vault_generic_secret.my_secret.data["secret"]}" 
}) `