# How to use StringList value of AWS SSM in cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have stored two subnets in aws ssm whose datatype is `StringList` like this s1,s2
and in lambda function I want to attach these two subnets using cloudformation template.
Lambda function will put the data to postgres database so for that I need to attch these subnets.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"

Resources:
  ExportToS3Function:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      FunctionName: testing-ssm
      CodeUri: testing-ssm/
      Environment:
        Variables:
          RDS_SECRET: XXXXXXX
          REGION: !Sub "${AWS::Region}"
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Timeout: 600
      MemorySize: 1750
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - '{{resolve:ssm:/testing/vpc/sg:1}}'
        SubnetIds: !Split [',','{{resolve:ssm:/testing/vpc/subnets:1}}']
      Role: !GetAtt testing-ssm.Arn
```

But above line `!Split [',','{{resolve:ssm:/testing/vpc/subnets:1}}']` giving me an error while deploying

Resource handler returned message: `"1 validation error detected: Value '[subnet-XXXXX, subnet-XXXXXX]' at 'vpcConfig.subnetIds' failed to satisfy constraint`

Comment: You have to provide more details. E.g. Complete template? How to reproduce your issue? Step by step?

Comment: @Marcin i have edited the question please go through it. I have gone through almost every documentation and StackOverflow but can not find related answer. My subnets are stored as StringList datatype in was ssm and I want them to use in cft

Comment: Did you try with `SubnetIds: ['{{resolve:ssm:/testing/vpc/subnets:1}}']`?

Comment: Not working same error occured.

Answer (score 0):

SSM needs to be a string type regardless of the type specified. Type is metadata for the client only. So if you have an array, you need to do `ssm_list -> value  = join(", ", subnet_ips_list)` when terraforming this SSM. Inside the template, you can reference it as `Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<CommaDelimitedList>'` and you can pass an array straight after `SubnetIds: ssm_list`

or one by one

```
SubnetIds:
  - !Select [0, !Split [ ", ", ssm_list ]]
```

maybe those will help as well: [How can I store a three element tuple in AWS SSM parameter with Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916301/how-can-i-store-a-three-element-tuple-in-aws-ssm-parameter-with-terraform)